# break each range (row) into two sub-ranges

Tags: r, perl, awk

I have an input like this:

```
120-160

200-220

400-500
.
.
.
```

I would link to break each range (row) into two sub-ranges:

```
120-140 141-160

200-210 211-220

400-450 451-500
.
.
.
```

and then print each column (range) into different files.

file 1:

```
120-140 

200-210 

400-450
.
.
.
```

file 2:

```
141-160

211-220

451-500
.
.
.
```

I could not do anything and no clue how to do it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution. Save as `break-range.pl`, run as `perl break-range.pl input`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $F1, '>', 'file1' or die $!;
open my $F2, '>', 'file2' or die $!;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (my ($low, $high) = /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/) {
        my $middle = int(($low + $high) / 2);
        print $F1 "$low-$middle\n";
        print $F2 $middle + 1, "-$high\n";
    }
}
close $F1;
close $F2;
```

For non-fixed number of output files, you can use something like the following, run it as `break-rangle.pl number-of-files input`. Note that it probably does not work if the number of files is greater than the size of an interval.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $number = shift;

my @FH;
for my $i (0 .. $number - 1) {
    open $FH[$i], '>', "file$i" or die $!;
}

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (my ($low, $high) = /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/) {
        my $step = ($high - $low) / $number;
        for my $i (0 .. $number - 1) {
            print {$FH[$i]} int($low + $i * $step) + ($i > 0), '-',
                            int($low + ($i + 1) * $step), "\n";
        }
    }
}
close $_ for @FH;
```

Comment: I changed your script for dividing into 5 ranges, but would please guide me the proper way of doing that? (I posted it as answer)

Answer (score 4):

You can use bash:

```
while IFS=- read min max; do
    mid=$(( (min+max)/2 ))
    printf "%d-%d\n" $min $mid >> file.1
    printf "%d-%d\n" $((mid+1)) $max >> file.2
done < input.file
```

The awk would be

```
awk -F- -v OFS=- '{
    mid = int(($1+$2)/2)
    print $1, mid   > "file.1"
    print mid+1, $2 > "file.2"
}' input.file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an R solution: Assuming you have imported the data into a vector `input`,

```
input <- c("120-160", "200-220", "400-500")
ranges <- strsplit(input, "-")
ranges <- lapply(ranges, as.numeric)
ranges <- lapply(ranges, function(x) c(x[1], mean(x), x[2]))

output1 <- sapply(ranges, function(x) sprintf("%d-%d", x[1], x[2]))
output2 <- sapply(ranges, function(x) sprintf("%d-%d", x[2]+1, x[3]))
```

You can then use `writeLines` to write the two files.